# Can I backup a physical phone and restore to emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Wondering if someone could point to directions or tell me if this is is not possible.

I would like to backup a physical phone. Then restore that to the emulator?

the phone is a cricket huawei ascend, I believe it is running 2.2

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: I do not think that you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is logical, but the answer is NO. You can't just create image of system and hope to get success in running the other emulator with that image. I have tried it earlier, not only on emulator but also on devices. I have successfully created an image of the mobile, but when running the other device/emulator, it fails. After digging a lot I understood that upper layer framework is same, or may change, but the lower level libraries, .so files are different and are not platform compatible.